# Do we hang up a telephone call, or just "hang up"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, direct-objects

I have to announce a message on a call  that is like this

> Alert!! There is an alarm from the system,to disarm the system, press 5, to ignore this call , hang up!!

Is this OK?  should I use *hang up the call* or is the *hang up* enough?

Comment: Unless the comma splice is audible, the sentence is fine :)

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան so hang up is OK ! no need to say hang up the call

Comment: You can check that independently: [hang up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hang-up). The reason it's just *hang up* is because it's the telephone receiver which is ["hung up" on its cradle](http://www.telephonecollecting.org/Bobs%20phones/Pages/Kellogg/Kellogg.htm).

Comment: here is how its going to be http://194.158.21.231:8081/MESSAGES/012099097112101108097071114111117112/AcapelaGroup_WebDemo_HTML/sounds/87618903_d68a9c55d40a9.mp3

Comment: Good thing punctuation and spacing are not audible, either. They are abysmal, and not even in a consistent way.

Comment: I used those to provide some audible pauses from the text to speech  software.

Comment: Please give questions useful titles. “Please help me with this” or “Is this correct?” does not tell anyone anything about what the question is about. The title of the question should correspond to the content of the question.

Comment: You can *hang up* or *hang up the phone*. You wouldn't hang up the call, at least not in AmE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [LDOCE](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hang_1#p008-001170665):

> **hang up** phrasal verb
>
> to finish a telephone conversation:
> *I said goodbye and hung up.*
>
> ---
>
> **hang something ↔ up**
>
> to hang clothes on a hook etc:
> *She took her coat off and hung it up.*

As you can see, they've got different meanings, and "*hang up*" alone is what you need in this context; adding "*a telephone call*" makes it redundant and incorrect.

Comment: Note that the former actually comes from "hanging up the handset", back in the days when hanging up was done by returning the handset to its rest position on the switchhook.

Answer (score 2):

The imperative "hang up" is sufficient, as "the telephone" is implied. What else would the listener hang up? In this case, it acts as an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 1):

Hang up itself means end a telephone conversation by cutting the connection. 
So using the term hang up is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- hang up.
- hang up the telephone.
- hang up the phone.

These three grammatical examples mean the same thing. Originally, it was physically part of the telephone that was hung off a hook which ended the call. Of course, it's a bit redundant to actually say the word *telephone*, as it's usually clear enough what *hang up* refers to.

You can't however *hang up the call*. It is quite difficult to hang a call on something!